# unquote and evaluate variable as column in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I would like to pass variable name to var and do all sorts of things including ggplot.

Apparently UQ works for data manipulation, but doesn't work for ggplot2. So my function "foo" works but "foo1" doesn't.

What's the best solution?

```
set.seed(100)

dat <- tibble(`a` = rbinom(100, 1, 0.2), `b` = rnorm(100))


foo <- function(var)
{
  var_q <- enquo(var)

  dat %>% mutate(`d` = UQ(var_q) + 1)

}

foo(`a`)


foo1 <- function(var)
{
  var_q <- enquo(var)

  dat %>% mutate(`d` = UQ(var_q) + 1) %>% ggplot(aes(x=UQ(var_q), y=`b`)) + geom_point()
}

foo1(`a`)
```

Comment: for ggplot you'll need `aes_string`

Comment: I sort of get this idea, but how would you actually do it if my "x" is from a string and "y" is an actual column name? something like this seems doesn't work     
foo1 <- function(var)
{
  var_q <- enquo(var)
  
  dat %>% mutate(`d` = UQ(var_q) + 1) %>% ggplot(aes_string(x=var_q, y="`b`")) + geom_point()
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foo1 <- function(var) {
  var_q <- enquo(var)

  dat %>% 
    mutate(`d` = (!!var_q) + 1) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x=eval(rlang::`!!`(var_q)), y=`b`)) + 
    geom_point()

 }
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation for your answer. Your post is currently flagged as low quality. People are here to also learn, not only to have their problems solved. Thank you.